# AWS CDK - Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, alarm, aws-cdk

Can someone provide some basic setup on how to create a simple cloudwatch alarm, alert, metric using Cdk?

I am extremely new to CDK -and using typescript.  I just need some startup guidance, where to create these ts file- I am abit confgused

Answer (score 1):

1. Cloudwatch alarm can be created using [Alarm CDK construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cloudwatch.Alarm.html).
2. Cloudwatch metric can be creates using [Metric class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cloudwatch.Metric.html).

```
new Alarm(this, "Errors", {
  alarmName: "MyTestAlarm",
  metric: new Metric({
    "metricName": "MyTestMetric",
    "namespace": "SampleApplicationName",
    "period": Duration.minutes(1),
    "unit": Unit.COUNT,
    "statistic": Statistic.SUM
  }),
  threshold: 0,
  comparisonOperator: ComparisonOperator.GREATER_THAN_THRESHOLD,
  treatMissingData: TreatMissingData.NOT_BREACHING,
  evaluationPeriods: 3
});
```

Please refer to the Cloudwatch CDK Typescript [overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-cloudwatch-readme.html) for more depth and understanding.

Also, [here's](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/typescript) a GitHub repository with CDK Typescript sample apps. These samples will help you with basic CDK app setup.

**Edit**

[Cloudwatch documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html) is a good place to understand the basic concepts.

Comment: Where's the data to create the metric specified? I don't understand what's namespace here.
I have to create CPU utilisation metric for my ECS service.Where do I put service name & where do I indicate ECS?

Answer (score 0):

```
 new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, "Errors", {
  alarmName: "AlertForEDITest",
  metric: new cloudwatch.Metric({
    "metricName": "NDMEDIMetricTest",
    "namespace": "NDMItemsTest",
    "period": Duration.minutes(1),
    "unit": cloudwatch.Unit.COUNT,
    "statistic": cloudwatch.Statistic.SUM
  }),
  threshold: 1,
  comparisonOperator: cloudwatch.ComparisonOperator.LESS_THAN_THRESHOLD,
  treatMissingData: cloudwatch.TreatMissingData.NOT_BREACHING,
  evaluationPeriods: 30
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Adding some explanation to the code, not just snippet, is the way to produce a great answer